# installation of vfsstream using pear

Tags: php, pear, vfs-stream

I need to setup `vfsStream` to use it with PHPUnit on my env. Unfortunately the project is very old and I cannot use composer. Instead I tried to install it using pear acording to [documentation](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream/wiki/Install). `Bovigo` channel is discovered properly but when I try to install `vfs` I get following stack trace:

```
[vagrant@dev site]$ pear install bovigo/vfsStream-beta

Warning: lstat(): Lstat failed for /var/cache/php-pear/ea87df910d5f186e8b68f01fb94241bcrest.cacheid in PEAR/REST.php on line 276
PHP Warning:  lstat(): Lstat failed for /var/cache/php-pear/ea87df910d5f186e8b68f01fb94241bcrest.cacheid in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/REST.php on line 276
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/share/pear/pearcmd.php:0
PHP   2. PEAR_Command_Common->run() /usr/share/pear/pearcmd.php:305
PHP   3. PEAR_Command_Install->doInstall() /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command/Common.php:271
PHP   4. PEAR_Downloader->download() /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command/Install.php:661
PHP   5. PEAR_Downloader_Package->initialize() /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Downloader.php:279
PHP   6. PEAR_Downloader_Package->_fromString() /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Downloader/Package.php:190
PHP   7. PEAR_Downloader->_getPackageDownloadUrl() /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Downloader/Package.php:1713
PHP   8. PEAR_REST_13->getDownloadURL() /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Downloader.php:850
PHP   9. PEAR_REST->retrieveData() /usr/share/pear/PEAR/REST/13.php:68
PHP  10. PEAR_REST->saveCache() /usr/share/pear/PEAR/REST.php:163
PHP  11. PEAR_REST->saveCacheFile() /usr/share/pear/PEAR/REST.php:246
PHP  12. lstat() /usr/share/pear/PEAR/REST.php:276
No releases available for package "pear.bovigo.org/vfsStream"
install failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might need to do that via sudo, e.g.

```
$ sudo pear ....
```

Comment: It does not report lack of rights - it says there's no such package instead... However I'll try on Monday.

Comment: Seems it worked. Strange but if it works then it's good! :) Thanks.